# how to split string with multiple special characters in oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, split

I have a string with 2 special characters as below

```
String :'PAN~HLASD4564P|VOTER_ID~VDD3455355'
```

I want output in 2 columns as below :

```
ID_TYPE       VALUE
-------       ------
PAN           HLASD4564P
VOTER_ID      VDD3455355
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSmzT.png)

Comment: Can the "value" ever be `null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CONNECT BY` and `REGEXP_SUBSTR` as follows:

```
SQL> WITH YOUR_DATA AS (
  2      SELECT 'PAN~HLASD4564P|VOTER_ID~VDD3455355' AS STR
  3      FROM DUAL
  4  ) -- Your query starts from here
  5  SELECT 
  6      REGEXP_SUBSTR(NEW_STR, '[^~]+', 1, 1) AS ID,
  7      REGEXP_SUBSTR(NEW_STR, '[^~]+', 1, 2) AS VALUE
  8  FROM
  9      (
 10          SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR, '[^|]+', 1, LEVEL) NEW_STR
 11          FROM YOUR_DATA
 12          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2
 13      );

ID         VALUE
---------- -------------
PAN        HLASD4564P
VOTER_ID   VDD3455355

SQL>
```

Comment: If this answer solved your question then please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so that your question is marked as resolved.

Comment: The OP showed the sample input with two encoded rows (id type and corresponding value). In principle he could have any number of such rows in an input string. If you modify the `CONNECT BY` condition to something like `LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(....)`, your query will solve the more general problem, where the number of rows in the output is not known beforehand. Note that you may also need to modify the code somewhat if the "value" (or the "id", but that's less likely) can be `null` - encoded as an empty substring in the input.

Comment: Yes i have modified the CONNECT BY condition to something like LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(....)

Answer (score 0):

```
    WITH your_data AS (
    SELECT
        'ISAT_FWASSAMBA_008' AS str
    FROM
        dual
) -- Your query starts from here
SELECT
    regexp_substr(new_str, '[^_]+', 1, 1) AS str1,
    regexp_substr(new_str, '[^_]+', 1, 2) AS str2,
    regexp_substr(new_str, '[^_]+', 1, 3) AS str3,
    regexp_substr(new_str, '[^_]+', 1, 4) AS str4
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            regexp_substr(str, '[^|]+', 1, level) new_str
        FROM
            your_data
        CONNECT BY level <= 1
    );
```

working perfect

[image]